# Favourite list on LocalStorage with React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, local-storage

I have created a favourite list with LocalStorage, but it adds one item at a time each time I reload the page. The elements are taken from a JSON

Here is an example of how my code works: https://www.codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-wood-d9y4zw?file=/src/App.js

```
const [ storageItem, setStorageItem ] = useState(() => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favourites") || "[]" ))
const isFavourited = storageItem.includes(blok._uid)

const handleToggleFavourite = () => {
    if (!isFavourited) {
        const newStorageItem = [...storageItem, blok._uid]
        setStorageItem(newStorageItem);
        localStorage.setItem("favourites", JSON.stringify(newStorageItem))
    } else {
        const newStorageItem = storageItem.filter((savedId) => savedId !== blok._uid)
        setStorageItem(newStorageItem);
        localStorage.setItem("favourites", JSON.stringify(newStorageItem))
    }
}
```

Comment: who is calling `handleToggleFavourite`?

Comment: Change the colour of a svg
`<svg onClick={handleToggleFavourite} viewBox="0 0 19 17" fill={isFavourited ? "#FFD3F3" : "none"} >
                            <path  />
                        </svg>`

Comment: Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates?  (Even if off-site, if the stack snippets are sandboxed to not allow local storage?)

Comment: Here I have given you an example. As you can see, if you select several elements before reloading the page, it will only save the last one selected https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-wood-d9y4zw?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you were using `useState` when mapping an object. Hooks `useState` can only be used in the topmost level of a functional component.

I've fixed a bit here is the new updated URL https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-lederberg-97fy54?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

you need to check where you are calling the method because it seems you are doing it in a useEffect or something like that and that’s why add the item when you reload the page

Comment: No, I did not call it in useEffect. It is not called in anything

Comment: Here I have given you an example. As you can see, if you select several elements before reloading the page, it will only save the last one selected https://www.codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-wood-d9y4zw?file=/src/App.js